# Regex for checking price format

Tags: php, mysql, regex, validation

I have this long validation going on with my form, everything seems to be getting checked except for the validation on the price to ensure it's the correct format which is basically a series of numbers followed by a decimal point and 2 more numbers i.e. 12.00 or 112.00 or 124.53, etc.

Here's my code which also checks to see if field is set and isn't empty as well as if the product name already exists.

```
 <?php


    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['product-name']) &&     !empty($_POST['product-name']) && isset($_POST['description']) && !empty(trim($_POST['description'])) && isset($_POST['price']) && !empty($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['category']) && !empty($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['spice']) && !empty($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['date-added']) && !empty($_POST['date-added'])){
                    $product_name = trim($_POST['product-name']);
        $description = trim($_POST['description']);
                    $price = $_POST['price'];
        $category = $_POST['category']; 
                    $spice = $_POST['spice'];  
                    $date_added = $_POST['date-added'];  
          $pattern = '/^\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$/';
          $pattern1 = '/^([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]{2})?$/';
          
   if(preg_match($pattern, $price)){
    $error = "<script language='javascript'>
        window.onload = function(){
            var divs = document.getElementById('error');
            divs.innerHTML = '<p style = \"color:#FF0000\">Price is in the  wrong format, correct format e.g. 10.00</p>';
        }
        </script>";

  }

  if(!isset($error)){
        $rows = getProductName($product_name);
                    if($rows > 0){
                                     echo "<script language='javascript'>
        window.onload = function(){
            var divs = document.getElementById('error');
            divs.innerHTML = '<p style = \"color:#FF0000\">Product name already exists!</p>';
        }
        </script>";
                    } else{
                        
                          insertProduct($product_name, $description, $price, $category, $spice, $date_added) ;
                    
                      echo "<script language='javascript'>
        window.onload = function(){
            var divs = document.getElementById('error');
            divs.innerHTML = '<p style = \"color:#FF0000\">Record Inserted Successfully!</p>';
        }
          </script>";
                    
               }
  } else{
       echo $error;
   }


   } else{ echo "<script language='javascript'>
        window.onload = function(){
            var divs = document.getElementById('error');
            divs.innerHTML = '<p style = \"color:#FF0000\">Please fill out all required (*) fields!</p>';
        }
          </script>";
   }


  ?>
```

It's most likely something simple but I can't seem to see where the issue is.

#### Update:

The form is too long but this is a condensed version containing the field: <sup>†</sup>

```html
<form method="post" action="addProduct.php">
  <ul class="form-style-1">
    <div id="error"></div>
    <h2>Add Product</h2>
    <li> <label>Price: <span class="required">*</span></label> <input type="text" name="price" class="field-long" placeholder="Enter Price" /> </li>
</form>
```

<sup>†</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Added per comment on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42685301/1575353) by Hydra at 2017-03-10 03:06:52Z</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot `!exclamation mark` since you want to make sure if your value **doesn't** match a specific pattern:

```
if(!preg_match($pattern, $price))
```

you could also use `is_float()` function that returns `true` if the value is float otherwise it will return `false`

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the check itself, I believe it isn't being hit for some reason so the validation isn't checked at all.

Comment: Your HTML Form!.

Comment: The forms too long but this is the field: 
<form method="post" action="addProduct.php">
<ul class="form-style-1">
    <div id="error"></div> 
     <h2>Add Product</h2>
   <li>
        <label>Price: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="price" class="field-long" placeholder="Enter Price"/>
    </li>
</form>

Comment: where is the rest of your form. please add your html code to your question so the community members could help you.